# c program of BFS. what is the role of db() here?

Tags: c

1. what is the role of db() here ? it is a BFS program but i am confused how to run that program. also how to print minimal level goal if there are more than one goal. what is the role of db() here ? it is a BFS program but i am confused how to run that program. also how to print minimal level goal if there are more than one goal.

   ```
    #include<conio.h>
      #include<stdio.h>
      #include<string.h>
      #include<malloc.h>
       #include<math.h>
            void input();
         void output();
          int db(int);
        void BFS(struct tree *);
        struct tree
             {
         char node[10];
           struct tree *left,*right;
           } *temp, *root=NULL,*t,*q[25];
        int d,a[10],jj,ii,ti,b,fi,ri;
        char ch[10];
         void main()
          {

          input();
          output();
           getch();
             }
          void input()
             {
          int n,m,r,i,f;
          printf("Enter the no of depth:-");
          scanf("%d",&d);
           n=pow(2,d+1)-1;
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            {
               printf("Enter the %d node name:-",i);
           scanf("%s",ch);
           temp=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
        strcpy(temp->node,ch);
         temp->left=NULL;
         temp->right=NULL;
        if(root==NULL)
           {
             root=temp;
          }
        else
          {
          t=root;
           r=db(i);
            for(f=1;f<r;f++)
          {
          if(a[f]==0)
          {
         t=t->left;
       }
          else
       {
         t=t->right;
       }
          }
            if(a[r]==0)
         {
         t->left=temp;
         }
         else
                    {
           t->right=temp;
        }
           }
             }
                  }
           void output()
               {
                 t=root;
               printf("\n Enter the name Goal:-");
           scanf("%s",ch);
              BFS(t);
                }
                int db(int n)
             { int ji=0;
                 while(n!=0)
                       {
               a[ji++]=n%2;
                     n=n/2;;
                  }


                ji--;
               return ji;



                            }
             BFS(struct tree *t)
              {
              int yes=0,index;
            fi=0;
              ri=1;
            q[fi]=t;
           printf("\n Breadth First search:-\n");
              while(fi<ri)
                 {
              t=q[fi++];
                printf("%s",t->node);
              if(strcmp(t->node,ch)==0)
                  {
               yes=1;
                index=fi;
                      }
                 if(t->left!=NULL)
                         {
                   q[ri++]=t->left;
                                    }
                      if(t->right!=NULL)
                         {
                        q[ri++]=t->right;
                              }
                                   }
                         if(yes==1)
           printf("\n Goal State Are Present at Node %d",index);
                          else
            printf("\n Goal State Are Not Present");
                    }
   ```

Comment: What's with the indentation?  It is very difficult to read your code.  At least have the good grace to (a) start functions at the left margin and (b) leave a blank line between the close brace of one function and the code (or comments) at the start of the next.  You need to explain more what your program is supposed to do.  You need to show some sample input, and the expected or actual output.  Please read about [Ask] and how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Also, please post compilable code; the BFS definition doesn't specify a return type (that's not been legal in standard C at any time in this millennium — though compilers often accept such code, sometimes (too often) by default, sometimes only if you request it).  It needs to be defined with `void` so it matches the declaration. —— The function `db` is defined (I missed it on first reading) and used.  The code is abominably indented.  I'm not going to look further at it until it is presentable.